# gitlab ci how to build dependent projects

Tags: maven, gitlab, continuous-integration

Having multiple projects in my gitlab.

The main project has a dependency in the maven to some of the other projects.
Now i'm trying to define a ci pipeline to the main project, looks so far:

```
image: maven:3-openjdk-11

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - package

build_job:
  stage: build

  script:
     - echo "Maven compile started"
     - "mvn -f the-core/pom.xml compile"

test_job:
  stage: test

  script:
      - echo "Maven test started"
      - "mvn test"

package_job:
   stage: package

   script:
      - echo "Maven packaging started"
      - "mvn package"
```

After running getting the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project the-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xyz.core:the-core:war:0.1.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.xyz.common:restful-client:jar:2.1, com.xyz.common:utilities:jar:2.1 Could not find artifact com.xyz.common:restful-client:jar:2.1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

I think i have to build the dependent project before, but not sure how to do this.

Comment: Your whole pipeline does not really make sense. With `clean install`, you already ran the `test` and the `package` phase as well, no need to repeat that.

Comment: Ok, thanks so far for the hint. Buit it doesn't solve the problem. Also with "mvn compile" the error remains.

Comment: Your dependencies should be published somewhere. If they're not published on mavencentral, then you need to publish them _somewhere_ and configure maven accordingly. For example, you can use the [gitlab maven packages registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/)